# install sharepoint 2010 on PC with cpu is only 32 bits

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I can't install sharepoint foundation 2010 on my PC because my CPU is only 32 bits.
The only way is to use virtual PC unfortunately it will be very heavy because I have only 3 Go as a RAM.

Have you solutions please?
thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot even install on `Virtual PC`. SharePoint 2010 can only be installed on Hyper-V or other virtualization software which supports 64 bit OS such as [`Virtual Box`](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Are you sure here that your CPU does not support 64 bits ? In most cases, its your OS version which would be running 32 bit windows. You can always wipe that and replace it with 64 bit OS.

If that is the case, you can do dual boot `Windows 2008 R2 x64 + SharePoint` along with your current OS, or have Hyper-V installed on Windows 2008 R2 OS and then SharePoint 2010 on Hyper-V image.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 is a 64 bit only app and thus requires a machine with a 64 bit Windows OS running on it (Windows 2008 Server or Windows 7).

Some 32 bit machines can run 64 bit guest Virtual Machines, but that depends on your architecture.

My advice to you is to upgrade your machine, as SharePoint and SQL require quite a bit of RAM to keep running.